# When is the transaction counter updated?

Tags: transactions, counters

At which point is the transaction counter of a Tezos account updated? Is it when the transaction is forged and emitted to the network or when the transaction is included in the blockchain?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account's counter is updated when the manager operation is included into the blockchain. It would be weird if the blockchain storage was affected by things not included in that blockchain :)

Comment: It makes total sense, thanks a lot!